# Datatable doesn't export first row header if table as two rows header

Tags: jquery, datatables, export-to-excel

I'm using jquery datatable to display data from my database.
I tried to export my data to excel it works correctly with a single row header. But when I try to add a title to my table (first row) it doesn't show up in the exported excel file. I only see the last header row.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr colspan="3">
            Employees
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Job</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>wick</td>
            <td>Plumber</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Queen</td>
            <td>eliz</td>
            <td>doctor</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here my js

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'excelHtml5', header: true },
        ]
        
    });
} );
```